# Lower Semicontinuous function

Tags: continuity

Let $(M,\delta)$ be Metric space, $f$ be a real function on $M$. Suppose $\{x \in M: f(x) > \alpha\}$ is open set in $M$ forall $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove $f$ is a lower semicontinuous function.

**Definition:** Let $(M,\delta)$ be Metric space. $f$ is a real function on $M$.We say, $f$ is a lower semicontinuous function if:

$\forall$ $\{x_m\}\longrightarrow x \in M$, we have $f(x)\leq \liminf_{m\rightarrow \infty} f(x_m)$

Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $\epsilon>0$. Show that $$\liminf_{m \to \infty} f(x_m) \ge f(x)-\epsilon$$ using the fact that $x \in \{y \in M: f(y) > f(x)-\epsilon\}$, which is an open set by assumption.

Comment: My exercise sheet asks one to prove this in the case of a first countable topological space. We do we use first countability?

Answer (score 1):

**Example** of semicontinuous function :

$$  f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2,\ x\neq 0 \\ -1,\ x=0 \end{cases} $$

Comment: How do you think this example?

Comment: Consider the condition $f(x) < {\rm lim\ inf}\ f(x_m)$ when $x_m\rightarrow x$. for instance $x_m=\frac{1}{m},\ x=0$.